# Tag 'capacity' is unclear

Tags: support, tags

The [capacity](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capacity) tag questions are either about *seating capacity* or *[airport capacity](https://nats.aero/blog/2013/08/airport-capacity-more-than-just-tarmac-and-terminals/).*

There are only 6 questions, would it be possible to split them? Suggested split:

- [seating-capacity](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seating-capacity)
- [airport-capacity](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-capacity)

---

An alternative choice would be to delete the tag altogether if other existing tags can be used. Suggested existing tags:

- [seats](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seats) x22 and [payload](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payload) x14
- [air-traffic-management](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-traffic-management) 6 questions

---

#### A week later...

I've done the split manually.